# Unable to run a .py file in cgi-bin by using ajax call from my .php file

Tags: python, webserver, cgi, javascript, sms

Hi guys:) I am using a Beagle Bone Black with Debian Wheezy to make a project. I have a small problem:I have my index.php in /var/www from there I call a python file called send_email.php using ajax:

`$.ajax({
    url:"/cgi-bin/send_email.py"
});`

It works properly (it sends me an email and I receive it).

But when I try to do the same thing with send_sms.py which has the following code inside

`import nexmo
client = nexmo.Client(key='XXXXX', secret='XXXXXXXXX')
client.send_message({'from': 'Nexmo number', 'to': 'My own number', 'text': 'Hello World'})`

When I run it from the terminal using: python send_sms.py, it works properly but when I call it using ajax it does not. I am confused as I thought that by calling any .py file in cgi-bin by using ajax, it would execute them (and it works for my send_email.py) but with send_sms.py it does not.

Thank you for your help, it is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. It looks like the Nexmo API does not work or something similar to it when it gets called from index.php using Ajax. I tried the same thing but with Twilio and it works properly.